# Why can I use FS=x to define awk's field separator only in some situations

Tags: bash, awk

There are a few different ways of setting awk's field separator. These include

- The command-line option `-F`: e.g. `awk -F '\t' '{…}' a.txt`
- Setting the `FS` variable at the beginning of the script: e.g. `awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {…} a.txt`
- Setting the `FS` variable with the option `-v`: e.g. `awk -v 'FS=\t' '{…}' a.txt`

However, I often use the following: `awk '{…}' FS='\t' a.txt` (I like it because it's quick to type, and also allows for `OFS='\t'` in a similar format.)

I've noticed that the field separator won't be set if the last two items are reversed. i.e. `awk '{…}' a.txt FS='\t'`

What does this syntax mean exactly? Hence, why is the order of the last two items so important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` processes its arguments in order.  Consider:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "BEGIN:", a } 
  { print FILENAME":", a }
  END { print "END:", a }
' file1 a=foo file2 a=bar
```

In this example, `awk` first parses the script and executes the BEGIN blocks before it even reads its arguments.  It then processes `file1`, then makes the variable assignment `a=foo`, then process `file2`, then makes the variable assignment `a=bar`, and finally processes the `END` blocks.

The first argument (loosely defining "argument" as elements of the command line that are not flags) passed to `awk` (assuming the absence of a `-f` flag) is the script to be executed.  The arguments following the script that contain an equals sign are variable assignments that are made after any BEGIN blocks and before input lines are processed *for files listed after the assignment*.  Arguments that do not contain an equal sign are files to be processed. So:

```
awk '{...}' a.txt FS='\t'
```

does not work because the argument `FS='\t'` is a variable assignment that is made after  `a.txt` is processed.  Since no files are listed after the assignment, it is never relevant to the processing.

Comment: This seems to be correct. `awk '{...}' a.txt FS='\t' b.txt` gives results consistent with this.

Answer (score 0):

Last input on `awk` need to be the file. That is why:

```
awk '{…}' a.txt FS='\t'  # this does not work
```

```
awk '{…}' FS='\t' a.txt  # this is OK
```

```
cat a.txt | awk '{…}' FS='\t'  # this is OK too
```

```
awk '{…}' FS='\t' a.txt  b.txt c.txt   # multiple file input OK
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I suspected that, but what _exactly_ does the `FS='\t'` part do anyway? I haven't been able to find documentation on this syntax anywhere. Is it equivalent to passing variables with the `-v` command-line option?

Comment: It sets the Field Separator to only TAB and not any blank.  So with `FS=\t` on this expression `one <space> two` is one filed, but `one <tab> two` it two fileds.  You can set variable in front of syntax using `-v FS=\t` or after syntax using `FS=\t`  Filed separator also can be set as an option using `-F\t`

Comment: I did the obvious and read the man page. It says `If  a  filename  on  the command line has the form var=val it is treated as a variable assignment.  The variable var will be assigned the value val.  (This happens after any BEGIN block(s) have been run.)` So it's slightly different to `-v` in that it's not available to the BEGIN block. However, it doesn't really explain why you can't put (real) filenames before this assignment.

Comment: I have not read all the page in the manual, just accepted that variable needs to be assigned before file names occurs.